# Broken Link in WP Site?

Tags: permalinks

I've built a test site for a client using a theme purchased from Template Monster. I can't seem to find out why the link is broken on this page. and the Template Monster support has extremely poor.

http://trustlabor.com/riverstonesalonspa/portfolio/

I renamed the stock theme "Portfolio" page to "Staff Bios" If I change the page permalink to: http://trustlabor.com/riverstonesalonspa/staffbios/
to match the new name of the page it is a broken link. It's still looking for the stock theme subdomain "portfolio."

Furthermore the page navigation below the thumbnail photos is also broken. If you try to navigate to from Page 1 to Page 2 of the staff photos you get a 404 error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL base is http://trustlabor.com/riverstonesalonspa/

You see one page in the URL http://trustlabor.com/riverstonesalonspa/portfolio/ because there is a page or a post with the link "/portfolio". You have to change the permalink in this page, from "portfolio" to "staffbios".

Comment: When I change the permalink to the new designation/name "Staff Bios" I then get a 404 error? I also get a 404 error if I try to click the thumbnail navigation to page 2 further down on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your rewrite rules are messed up. Maybe you should try to flush them and see if it works...

Put `flush_rewrite_rules( true );` somewhere in your functions.php

Don't forget to delete that line afterwards, as you don't want to flush your rewrite rules on every pageload.

Comment: You can easily flush the rewrite rules by simply visiting the Permalinks setting page in the WP Admin (Settings -> Permalinks). Just visiting the Permalinks settings page is enough. You don't need to make any changes or update the settings.

Comment: You can easily flush the rewrite rules by simply visiting the Permalinks setting page in the WP Admin (Settings -> Permalinks). Just visiting the Permalinks settings page is enough. You don't need to make any changes or update the settings.